# How can I display a tooltip on a disabled button?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, atl, wtl

I have a button which is disabled with `EnableWindow(false);`

However, at the same time, I want to display a tooltip on the disabled button via a `CToolTipCtrl`.

The problem is that `EnableWindow(false)` has blocked all mouse events which would normally be triggered on the client area of the button.

I have already read this blog:

[Why can’t I display a tooltip for a disabled window?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070405-00/?p=27363)

I am pretty sure I could make this happen with some redirecting of messages and `PreTranslateMessage()`, but I am rather looking for a way which wouldn't force me to rearrange all of my message maps just to have this little feature working.

Is there any trick or workaround to fix this?

Comment: If you use a [tracking tooltip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298405(v=vs.85).aspx) you can position and show it however you want.

Comment: I don't use CToolTipCtrl directly, I just handle TTN_NEEDTEXT so always get the message. Have you tried setting the TTS_ALWAYSTIP style?